# Append and Prepend contents of a div by class

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress

My database is returning the URL of an image instead of the image, via a plugin.

```
<div class="carimagebox">http://fastcarfinance.inspirationincbeta.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/porscheTest-1.jpg</div>
```

Can I append and prepend with HTML via PHP or Javascript?

```
<div class="carimagebox"><img src="http://fastcarfinance.inspirationincbeta.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/porscheTest-1.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: so you want to take the URL and to replace it with img src with that URL?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to replace the image tag with the correct html image tag.

```
$html = '<div class="carimagebox">...</div>';
$regex = '~<div class="carimagebox">(http://.*?\.jpg)</div>~';
$newhtml = preg_replace($regex, '<div class="carimagebox"><img src="$1" /></div>", $html);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use **jQuery**:

```
var x = $('.carimagebox').html(); 
$('.carimagebox').html("<img src='"+x+"' />");
```

You can try [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zarxnewo/)

For reference [jQuery .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

If you want to know what is **jQuery**, and what is it you can watch here [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

In **JavaScript** you can do so:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("carimagebox");
document.getElementsByClassName("carimagebox")[0].innerHTML = "<img src='"+x[0].innerHTML+"' />";
```

Comment: I see that this should work, but it doesn't, could another script be blocking it?

Comment: @Ruth - The important thing is to understand which of the two methods you are using. If you are using jQuery you must have embedded within your file (see the guide that I posted) otherwise for JavaScript should work without problems. Otherwise insert additional code that let's figure out what's wrong!

Comment: I have tried both. Does this part have to be in the head section or can it be anywhere in the page <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: @Ruth - Look here: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ . If you think my answer is great, please Vote Up!

Comment: I'm doing it correctly, just not working, so I expect another script is stopping it somewhere. Thanks for your help, the example is good.

Answer (score -1):

By using jQuery:

```
<script>
    var imgUrl = $('.carimagebox').html();
    $('.carimagebox').html('<img src="'+imgUrl+'">');
</script>
```